# What projection (transformation) is it?

Tags: linear-algebra, data-analysis, projection

Suppose I have a 3D scattered data

$$(A_1,B_1,Z_1)$$$$(A_2,B_3,Z_3)$$$$(A_3,B_3,Z_3)$$$$...$$$$(A_n,B_n,Z_n),$$ shown schematically in the picture below (left) and there is no order in the data.

[image]

Now, I build a map from 3D space to 2D space by dividing the first coordinates by the second coordinates, in the following way:
$$(A_1,B_1,Z_1)\rightarrow(\frac{A_1}{B_1},Z_1)$$$$(A_2,B_3,Z_3)\rightarrow(\frac{A_2}{B_2},Z_2)$$$$(A_3,B_3,Z_3)\rightarrow(\frac{A_3}{B_3},Z_3)$$$$...$$$$(A_n,B_n,Z_n)\rightarrow(\frac{A_n}{B_n},Z_n)$$
So now I have a 2D scattered data with the corresponding plot schematically represented on the right of the figure.

What does this map represent mathematically? What operation does it correspond to? It looks very much like some kind of projection... In which case what kind of projection is that? Onto a plane, or onto a curved surface? Orthogonal or non-orthogonal? How can I insert 2D plane with coordinates ($\frac{A}{B},Z$) in the initial 3D space with coordinates $(A,B,Z)$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From each data point $(A_i,B_i,Z_i,)$ find the nearest point on the $Z$ axis,
which is $(0,0,Z_i).$
Construct the line between those two points.
The point where that line intersects the plane $B = 1$
is $\left(\frac{A_i}{B_i}, 1, Z_i\right).$
You can eliminate the middle coordinate, which is always $1,$
and write the projected pont as $\left(\frac{A_i}{B_i}, Z_i\right).$
The axes for those coordinates are simply copies of the $A$ and $Z$ axes,
translated from the plane $B=0$ to the plane $B=1;$
specifically, you can use the lines $B=1,Z=0$ and $A=0,B=1$ as the new axes.

This projection is a kind of hybrid of orthogonal and central projections onto the plane $B=1.$
In any plane containing the $Z$ axis, the projection takes points orthogonally onto a line parallel to the $Z$ axis.
But in any plane parallel to the $A,B$ plane, the projection is a central projection through a point with coordinates $(0,0,Z).$

Comment: What would be the suitable coordinates in the plane $B=1$? Can the transformation be considered as a Mobius transformation (inversion) with some non-trivial scaling?

Comment: This does not look like a Mobius transformation to me. It goes from three dimensions to two, it's not conformal, and it's not invertible.

Comment: If you ignore $Z$ coordinate, and add a constant number as a second dimension to the result, then it would look like $(A_i,B_i)\rightarrow(const,\frac{A_i}{B_i})$ or $(A_i,B_i)\rightarrow(\frac{A_i}{B_i},const)$. Then you can also put the system into the complex space, second coordinates are imaginary numbers. Would it be a Mobius transformation in this case?

Comment: A Mobius transformation takes one complex number as input, not two, and it is invertible, while this transformation is not. What this transformation actually does in any plane with constant $Z$ is actually very simple: as I already wrote, it is the projection of the whole plane onto the line $B=1,$ using the origin as the central projection point. Why do you want it to be a Mobius transformation?

Comment: Dont know why... OK, thanks for your reply!